# How to make floating objects

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to make a floating item in Minecraft.

Here is a great example made on the Hypixel server:

[image]

Comment: just saying in the text next to the picture, it was not in the hypixel server, it was on one of his adventure maps!

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice Bukkit plugin names [ShowCaseStandalone](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/scs/) that allows what you want.

Otherwise, there is a second solution. As explained by Skylinerw on [minecraftforum.net](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2425934-zero-gravity-item-entitys),

> You can summon the item entity riding an invisible armor stand that
>   has NoGravity set to 1:
>
> ```
> /summon Item ~ ~5 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:1},Riding:{id:ArmorStand,Marker:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1}}
> ```

Comment: That summoning command is outdated for 1.9. You now have to summon an armorstand that has an item as their passenger. I.e. `/summon ArmorStand ~ ~5 ~ {Marker:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1,Passengers:[{id:Item,tag:{Item:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:1}}}]}`

Comment: Does this work for 1.9+?

Comment: @kevinbestkiller Yes, the answer has been modified to work for version 1.9+

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working but thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 3):

You dont even have to use a plugin, you can do that with commands.
There is a really good editor which generates the command for you:
http://haselkern.github.io/Minecraft-ArmorStand/

In your case there are 3 Armor stands with diffrent arm positions, all of them are invisible holding a Iron sword.

Comment: I really like this website for making thing! Thanks a lot :D